# How to align two React components horizontally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have two React components that I want to align horizontally next to each other. I use Material-UI's Grid to align components (but other solutions are also welcome). The problem is that components `InputVariables` and `Chart` are placed on top of each other (as two rows) instead of being aligned horizontally in a single row. What am I doing wrong?

Current alignment:

```
| InputVariables | 
| Chart          |
|         Button |
```

Desired alignment:

```
| InputVariables | Chart |
|                 Button |
```

**Main component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import InputVariables from './checkout/InputVariables';
import Chart from './chart/Chart';


const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 120,
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
  layout: {
    width: 'auto',
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    [theme.breakpoints.up(600 + theme.spacing.unit * 2 * 2)]: {
      width: 600,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
    },
  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    [theme.breakpoints.up(600 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 6,
      marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 6,
      padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    },
  },
  buttons: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

class MainForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <main className={classes.layout}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h4" align="center">
              Title goes here
            </Typography>


            <Grid container spacing={24}>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <InputVariables />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Chart />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={24}>
                    <div className={classes.buttons}>
                        <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.button}
                        >
                           Check
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

          </Paper>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

MainForm.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MainForm);
```

**Chart.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } from 'recharts';
import './Chart.css';

const data = [
    {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
    {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
    {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
    {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
    {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
    {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
    {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];

function Chart() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
                margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
                <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
                <YAxis/>
                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
                <Tooltip/>
                <Legend />
                <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
                {/* <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" /> */}
            </LineChart>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Chart;
```

**InputVariables.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

function InputVariables() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Set input variables of a model
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            id="address2"
            name="address2"
            label="Address line 2"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="billing address-line2"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField id="state" name="state" label="State/Province/Region" fullWidth />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="zip"
            name="zip"
            label="Zip / Postal code"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="billing postal-code"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="country"
            name="country"
            label="Country"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="billing country"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox color="secondary" name="saveAddress" value="yes" />}
            label="Use this address for payment details"
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default InputVariables;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Material-UI, you can use a Grid component and place two grid items occupying half the row size.

Material-UI has a 12 columns grid system (similar to bootstrap) which means for an item to occupy half the size, you give it a 6 columns size.

Check the `item xs{6}` below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
  flexGrow: 1,
},
paper: {
  padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
},
});


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
  );
}
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

In your example, you are using xs={12} and that will make your item occupy all columns in the row forcing the next item to skip to the next line.

Comment: do you know how to achieve the same result using Grid of Material-UI?

Comment: Updated the answer to explain why your problem was happening.